# Rails query doesn't work without pluck

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following query

```
def all_categories
    Category.includes(:categorizations).joins("INNER JOIN galleries ON categorizations.categorizeable_type = 'Gallery' AND categorizations.categorizeable_id = galleries.id").where("galleries.galleriable_id = :brand_id AND galleries.galleriable_type = 'Brand'", brand_id: brand_id).distinct
  end
```

which results in the SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN galleries ON categorizations.categorizeable_type = 'Gallery' AND categorizations.categorizeable_id = galleries.id WHERE (galleries.galleriable_id = 1093 AND galleries.galleriable_type = 'Brand')
```

which doesn't work and gives an error of

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categorizations"
LINE 1: ...ries".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN galleries ON categoriza...
```

however, this does work

```
 def categories_names
    all_categories.pluck("name")
  end
```

which results in the following SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT "categories"."name" FROM "categories" LEFT OUTER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categorizations"."category_id" = "categories"."id" INNER JOIN galleries ON categorizations.categorizeable_type = 'Gallery' AND categorizations.categorizeable_id = galleries.id WHERE (galleries.galleriable_id = 1093 AND galleries.galleriable_type = 'Brand')
```

is there a way to have `all_categories` without the pluck?

Comment: As a database developer bought here by the [tag:postgresql] tag, not a rails person, what's a "pluck"?

Comment: you didn't specify `select`. `Category.includes(:categorizations).joins("INNER JOIN galleries ON categorizations.categorizeable_type = 'Gallery' AND categorizations.categorizeable_id = galleries.id").where("galleries.galleriable_id = :brand_id AND galleries.galleriable_type = 'Brand'", brand_id: brand_id).select(:name).distinct`

Comment: You need to specify what field(s) should be DISTINCT

Comment: @CraigRinger pluck is rails way of including a select into a sql query. so pluck(field) is equivalent to select field, sort of. That is why I included the sql generated, maybe the problem is in there

Comment: @fl00r but distinct (according to http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct) should return unique records

Comment: for unique category record I should include distinct on category.id?

Comment: yes, I believe, `.select(:id).distinct`